# Why does the BERT NSP head linear layer have two outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, transformer, bert

Here's the code in question.

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L491

```
class BertOnlyNSPHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_relationship = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, 2)

    def forward(self, pooled_output):
        seq_relationship_score = self.seq_relationship(pooled_output)
        return seq_relationship_score
```

I think it was just ranking how likely one sentence would follow another? Wouldn't it be one score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be inherited from the original Google implementation, which also uses 2 outputs (https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_pretraining.py#L293). I can see two possible reasons that the original implementation uses 2 outputs:

1. They are using the cross entropy loss, which typically works with log probabilities. To get probabilities they use softmax activation, which requires an output for each class. It is possible, of course, to compute cross entropy from sigmoid activations (which would correspond to a 1-output architecture), but [there seems to be some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058867/sigmoid-output-can-it-be-interpreted-as-probability) as to whether the output of the sigmoid function should be used as a probability.
2. Using 2 outputs can simplify the computation of the binary cross entropy loss, which, in typical Google fashion, is computed using low-level tensorflow ops rather than with `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. Specifically,

```
-tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs, axis=-1)
```

where `one_hot_labels` and `log_probs` are $\mathbb{R}^{N \times 2}$, is much easier to read than

```
-tf.reduce_sum(binary_labels * tf.math.log(probs) + (1 - binary_labels) + tf.math.log(1 - probs))
```

where `binary_labels` and `probs` are $\mathbb{R}^N$.